# Setting Cover page and Last page with mPDF

Tags: php, mpdf

I'm attempting to Upload a PDF as a template for the cover page, then add html for the middle pages, then add a PDF as a template again for the final page.

Here is my code right now:

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['mode' => 'utf-8', 'format' => 'A4']);
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->enableImports = true;
$mpdf->debug = true;
$mpdf->SetImportUse();


//Set Cover Page Template
$pagecount = $mpdf->SetSourceFile('site/themes/raven/pdf/cover-page.pdf');
$tplId = $mpdf->ImportPage($pagecount);
$actualsize = $mpdf->SetPageTemplate($tplId);

// Add First page
$mpdf->AddPage();


//Write Content on Inside Pages

$html= (string) get_content("/print-menu");
$mpdf->AddPage();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);


//Set Last Page Template
$pagecount2 = $mpdf->SetSourceFile('site/themes/raven/pdf/last-page.pdf');
$tplId2 = $mpdf->ImportPage($pagecount2);
$actualsize2 = $mpdf->SetPageTemplate($tplId2);

//Add Last Page
$mpdf->AddPage();




$mpdf->Output();
```

I've tried UseTemplate() and UsePageTemplate() and tried changing the order of operations. It works on the first page, however the last page appears as a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
In my case, the solution was to set the background-color to transparent, because there was set a background-color in the content. So the background will be rendered over the last page